# Wine http port not responding (Multi-port application)

Tags: networking, docker, wine, steam, games

we have a long term problem with our wine-docker game server. The Game is running fine but it offers a remote client on a http port (8080) which does not respond. I thought maybe someone here who is not into games but into wine could help us solving the problem.

The game i'm talking about is Space Engineers, sadly coming only with a windows server and windows client, so we created a docker with wine to run it on linux servers. The game itself is running fine so far (on my vps) but nobody got the remote client connected to the server on that said http port.

Link to git repo: https://github.com/Devidian/docker-spaceengineers

The game log indicates that the Remote Server listener was started and listening on port 8080.

Any idea how to fix or further inspect the issue?

--UPDATE--
as requested, the composer file i use:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  se-server:
    #build: .
    image: devidian/spaceengineers:winestaging
    container_name: se-ds-docker
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      # left side: your docker-host machine
      # right side: the paths in the image (!!do not change!!)
      - /appdata/space-engineers/instances:/appdata/space-engineers/instances
      - /appdata/space-engineers/SpaceEngineersDedicated:/appdata/space-engineers/SpaceEngineersDedicated
      - /appdata/space-engineers/steamcmd:/root/.steam
    ports:
      - target: 8080
        published: 18080
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 27016
        published: 27016
        protocol: udp
        mode: host
    environment: 
      - WINEDEBUG=-all
      - INSTANCE_NAME=Debian
      - PUBLIC_IP=--REDACTED--
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your docker-compose does not publish port 8080, so no external program could connect to it.

Comment: The compose file i use on my server is different from the repo and does publish the port. The repo file is just an example for others.

Comment: could you please add that information to the question itself? That way, I can remove my not-answer answer here :)